# How to calculate min/max keys of map?

Tags: java, dictionary, max, min

I have an `array` of elements where each element is of type `Map`

[image]

How to find Minimum and Maximum of Keys of a `Map<String,float>`

[image]

My Code :

[image]

Please help.

Comment: @Bunny, just get the keySet from the map and iterate through the set to find min and max

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the code as text, not as screenshot. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Downvoted because code as image instead of text, can not view on my device.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use Comparator and you create ascending order value arraylist

```
public static ArrayList<ObjectA> getObjectAList() {

    ArrayList<ObjectA> objectAList = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.sort(objectAList, ObjectA.objectAValue);

    return objectAList;
}
public class ObjectA{
/* Comparator for sorting the list by value */
public static Comparator<ObjectA> objectAValue = new Comparator<ObjectA>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(ObjectA object1, ObjectA object2) {

        float value1 = object1.getValue();
        float value2 = object2.getValue();

        /* For ascending order */
        return Float.floatToIntBits(value1)-Float.floatToIntBits(value2);

    }
};
```

}